# Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Android Android Studio1\uninstall.exe'

Tags: android, android-studio

I was Uninstalling android studio from setting/Apps But it was saying Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Android Android Studio1\uninstall.exe'.
I have attached image of error -
[Error while uninstalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeWgZ.png)

Comment: Might be corrupt files. Check if Android Studio is shown in Installed programs. If not, you can delete the files.

Comment: My install of Arctic Fox also has no unistaller.exe - seems like a problem with the AS install file.

Comment: Android Studio is Installed correctly.
If we delete all files (including cache )  and again if we install android studio then it show previous android studio setting.